# Get the average with quantity

Tags: sql, math, sum, average

I have a problem to calculate easily some simple average. My table :

```
id / user / action     / data
1  / a    / unit_price / 40
2  / a    / quantity   / 1
3  / b    / unit_price / 70
4  / b    / quantity   / 2
```

Unit_price is a price for a user and quantity is quantity. So there i should get : 
(40 + 70 + 70) / 3 = 60

If i do an

`(AVG(action) WHERE action = unit_price)`

I get :

`(70+40)/2 = 55`

If I do an

`(SUM(action) WHERE action = unit_price) / (SUM(action) WHERE action = quantity)`

I get :

`110 / 3 = 36.6`

The easiest way I found is to don't put the unit_price but the global price then make a division in the PHP code to get the unit_price, but I was hoping SQL could do something for me.

Comment: I don't think any of your solutions can work but i need to be more specific : 1/that's only a part of a global request so i think i'll not be able to add more join and inside SELECT 2/ Get a column unit_price and separate colum quantity will not change the problem 3/ and yes, i don't want the avg price for a specific user but the global 4/ the right answer passed by a multiplication of quantity and unit_price for each user then classic avg math

Comment: Lamak's and Olivier's answer seem to answert your question perfectly. (Under some assumptions) bluefeet's and Raphael's as well. If your query/requirements are more complex, the answerers have no psychic powers to guess what those are.

Comment: ok i get good answers. Just need to find out how to put it in my big query. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select coalesce(sum(quantity * unit_price) /sum(quantity), 0) from
(select 
   sum(case when action='unit_price' then data else 0 end) as unit_price,
   sum(case when action='quantity' then data else 0 end) as quantity 
 from test
group by user) as a
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edf0f/13)

Comment: Raphael - quick SQL Fiddle tip - you can copy and paste OP's sample data into the "Text to DDL" tool to quickly build the tables and data needed to query against.  For example, here is your query running against a schema that I build by doing just that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfd1a/1

Comment: @JakeFeasel oh, oh, you save my day (which is just beginning ,that's a good start). Thx !

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this which basically pivots the data to a more usable format and then gets the values that you need:

```
select avg(unit_price) AvgUnitPrice, 
  sum(unit_price*quantity)/sum(quantity) AvgPrice
from
(
  select user,
    max(case when action = 'unit_price' then data end) unit_price,
    max(case when action = 'quantity' then data end) quantity
  from table1
  group by user
) x;
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89852/23)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, obviously your table design is not optimal, you should have `unit_price` and `quantity` as separate columns. But, working with what you have, try this:

```
SELECT SUM(A.data*B.data)/SUM(B.data) Calculation
FROM (  SELECT user, data
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE action = 'unit_price') AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT user, data
            FROM YourTable
            WHERE action = 'quantity') AS B
ON A.user = B.user
```

Comment: OPs question needs clarifying, but it seems he wants the result to be (SUM of Unit Price) / (Sum of Quantity), without boiling it down by user.

Comment: @Jim - I misread the question, though I think that op wants something different that what I had posted, so I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @ypercube - where did that came from?

Answer (score 2):

I would join the table to itself in order to get the two records beloning together on one line

```
SELECT
    SUM(unit_price * quantity) / SUM(quantity) AS average_unit_price
FROM
    (SELECT
        U.data AS unit_price, Q.data AS quantity
    FROM
        theTable U
        INNER JOIN theTable Q
            ON U.user = Q.user
    WHERE
        U.action = 'unit_price' AND
        Q.action = 'quantity')
```

If you have more than two records per user and the ids of the both records are consequtive, then you would have to change the WHERE-clause to

```
    WHERE
        U.action = 'unit_price' AND
        Q.action = 'quantity' AND
        U.id + 1 = Q.id
```

---

Note:

If you calculate `AVG(unit_price * quantity)` you get the average sum per user.

> (1*40 + 2*70) / 2 = 90

If you calculate `SUM(unit_price * quantity) / SUM(quantity)` you get the average unit price.

> (1*40 + 2*70) / 3 = 60

Comment: but i get only one table. Why A and B ? I don't get it. (i add a comment to my question to be more specific)

Comment: `A` and `B` are aliases (I changed them to `U` for unit_price and `Q` for quantity respectively now). There is only one table (`theTable`), but I use it twice. Once I give it the name `U` and once `Q`. This allows me to treat them as if they were two different tables. From `U` I take only the records with the unit prices, from `Q` only the records with the quantities and join them by the user. This query is used as sub-query and is therefore between parentheses (). It is used like a new table having two columns `unit_price` and `quantity` and serves as the source table of the outer SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Your table design doesn't look good.

Make 2 tables instead:

```
ITEM
   ItemId int not null PK, 
   Name varchar(200) not null, 
   UnitPrice decimal (10,2) not null

SALES
   SalesId int not null PK, 
   ItemId int not null FK, 
   Quantity decimal(10,2)
```

PK - primary key, FK - foreign key

Average:

```
select 
  I.Name, avg(I.UnitPrice * S.Quantity) as avgSales
from 
  Sales S 
  join Items I on I.ItemId = S.ItemId
group by 
  I.Name
```

Comment: While it might be the case that table structure isn't ideal, sometimes changing the schema isn't possible.  What the OP is asking is perfectly possible given his current schema.

Comment: Yes I agree, but we should make clear that the solution is not "ideal". If there are reasons for that it should be made explicit.

Comment: Well i know it looks like a simple ordre website but it's not and i really need to get this two informations in the same table. What i should say is that my global queries is much complicate than the part i show up...

Comment: i add a comment to my question to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work; syntax might not be perfect since I didn't try it out, but you get the main idea at least.

```
SELECT sumUnitPrice.sum / sumQuantity.sum
FROM
(
  (SELECT SUM(data) as sum
  FROM WhateverTheHellYourTableIsNamed
  WHERE action = 'unit_price') sumUnitPrice

  (SELECT SUM(data) as sum
  FROM WhateverTheHellYourTableIsNamed
  WHERE action = 'quantity') sumQuantity
)
```